# Load audio in DOCUMENTS when UITableView "cell" is pressed

Tags: ios, uitableview, audio, avfoundation, documents

I have a UITableView displaying a llist f files in the Documents Directory... and I want it to play the audio file in the Documents directory when pressed...

It runs with no errores but doesn't play the audio when pressed...

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.caf",indexPath.row+1]];
NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fileName];

NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:audioURL];

NSError *error;

_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:&error];

    _audioPlayer.delegate = self;
        [_audioPlayer play];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

```
NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL URLWithString:fileName];
```

to this:

```
NSURL *audioURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName isDirectory:NO];
```

And then just do:

```
 if(_audioPlayer == nil)
    {
        _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        _audioPlayer = [self.audioAlert initWithContentsOfURL:audioURL error:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To start out, the best way to declare a files path is this

```
- (NSString *)docsdir {
return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

in your header, declare`NSString *Path;`

then, declare the path like this when the view loads

```
Path = [[self docsdir]stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.caf",indexPath.row+1]];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:Path]) {


    [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row+1] ofType:@"caf"] toPath:Path error:nil];


}
```

now to play it, do this

```
    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:Path] error:&error];
player.delegate = self;
[player play];
```