# Accessing and playing sound files through a table view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I'm trying to make a basic voice memo app, and I'm able to record a sound and play it back, and I put the file names on a table view.

Now I would like to play the sound when I click on the table view row, and I can't get the sound to play back.

I've been taking queues from this post: [Load audio in DOCUMENTS when UITableView "cell" is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14554462/load-audio-in-documents-when-uitableview-cell-is-pressed)

Here is my full code. The most relevant part is at the very bottom:

```
#import "ViewController.h"


@interface ViewController () {
AVAudioRecorder *recorder;
AVAudioPlayer *player;
NSArray *filePathsArray;
NSArray *tableData;
NSString *recorderFilePath;
NSURL *url;

}
@end

@implementation ViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

// Disable Stop/Play button when application launches
[self.stopButton setEnabled:NO];
[self.playButton setEnabled:NO];
[self audioSetUp];

}

-(void) audioSetUp {
// Set the audio file
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSString *fileName = [date description];
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject],
                           fileName,
                           nil];
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];
// Setup audio session
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];



// Define the recorder setting
NSMutableDictionary *recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
[recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

// Initiate and prepare the recorder
recorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:url settings:recordSetting error:NULL];
recorder.delegate = self;
recorder.meteringEnabled = YES;
[recorder prepareToRecord];

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}


cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}


- (IBAction)recordPauseButton:(UIButton *)sender {
}
- (IBAction)recordPauseTapped:(id)sender {
// Stop the audio player before recording
if (player.playing) {
    [player stop];
}

if (!recorder.recording) {
    AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [session setActive:YES error:nil];

    // Start recording
    [recorder record];
    [self.recordPauseButton setTitle:@"Pause" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

} else {

    // Pause recording
    [recorder pause];
    [self.recordPauseButton setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

[self.stopButton setEnabled:YES];
[self.playButton setEnabled:NO];
}

- (IBAction)stopTapped:(id)sender {
[recorder stop];



//pulling up saved data for the table view
NSArray *folders = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsFolder = [folders objectAtIndex:0];

tableData = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsFolder error:nil];
[self.tableView reloadData];

AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
//[self audioSetUp];

}

- (IBAction)playTapped:(id)sender {
if (!recorder.recording){
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recorder.url error:nil];
    [player setDelegate:self];
    [player play];
}
}

- (void) audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)avrecorder successfully:(BOOL)flag{
[self.recordPauseButton setTitle:@"Record" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.stopButton setEnabled:NO];
[self.playButton setEnabled:YES];
}

- (void) audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag{
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Done"
                                                message: @"Finish playing the recording!"
                                               delegate: nil
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[self audioSetUp];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath             {

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.caf",indexPath.row]];
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: fileName isDirectory:NO];

if(player == nil)
    {
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    }

NSError *error;

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

player.delegate = self;
[player play];

}

@end
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and see if `player` is `nil` and if so, check `error`.

Comment: I'd also add to check whether `url` is `nil` and add the `prepareToPlay` message before `play`

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution to my dilemma. Thanks for @fumoboy007 and @bgfriend for the suggestions.

Here is how I changed up the last part of my code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath     {

NSArray *folders = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsFolder = [folders objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",documentsFolder,[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName isDirectory:
       NO];


if(player == nil)
    {
        player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    }

NSError *error;

player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];

player.delegate = self;
[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
}
```

Now it works like a charm!